# Unable to print out JPG image referenced from an XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I am trying to get a series of jpg images printed out with text from an XML file. I have cut and pasted my code below and the xml file.
**HTML/JavaScript:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <style>
 #header{

 text-align:center;

 }

 #middle{

 text-align:center;

 }

 </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//function getList () {
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$("p").click(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
            var team =
                xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fixtures");
            var html = "";
            for (i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
                html += 
                  //  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image1")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>" +    
                    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("match")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>" +
                   xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image2")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>" +//
                    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("location")[i] .childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>" + 
                    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("date")[i] .childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br><br>"; 
            }
            document.getElementById("matchlist").innerHTML = html;

        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "fixtures.xml", true);
    xhr.send();

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id = "header"><h1>UEFA European Championship 2016 Final Tournament - Group Stage</h1></div>
<div id = "middle"  >

    <ul id="matchlist" ></ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**XML (fixtures.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xpsport2.xsl"?>
<Fixtures>
<fixtures field="Football">
    <image1 src="http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/50x50/BEL.png" alt="Belgium"></image1>
    <image2 src="http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/50x50/IRL.png" alt="Republic of Ireland"></image2>
            <match>Belgium v Rep. of Ireland</match>
            <location>Stade Bollaert-Delelis, Lens</location>
            <date>Saturday, June 11</date>
      </fixtures>
      <fixtures field="Football">
          <image1 src="images\ireland.jpg"  ></image1>
           <image2 src="images\sweden.jpg"></image2>
            <match>Rep. of Ireland v Sweden</match>
            <location>Stade de France, Paris</location>
            <date> Monday.13 june 2016</date>
      </fixtures>
      <fixtures field="Football">
       <image1 src="images\belgium.jpg" />
       <image2 src="images\sweden.jpg"/>   
       <match> Sweden v Belgium</match>
            <location>Stade Pierre Mauroy, Lille</location>
            <date>Tuesday, June 14 </date>
      </fixtures>

      <fixtures field="Football">
          <image1 src="images\italy.jpg"/>  
          <image2 src="images\sweden.jpg"/>
       <match>Italy v Sweden</match>
            <location>Stade de Bordeaux,Bordeaux</location>
            <date> Monday,18  June </date>
      </fixtures>
       <fixtures field="Football">
           <image1  src="images\italy.jpg"  />
           <image2 src="images\ireland.jpg"/>
       <match>Italy v Rep. of Ireland</match>
            <location>Grand Stade Lille Métropole, Lille</location>
            <date>Friday, 22 June </date>
      </fixtures>
</Fixtures>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a jQuery tag here, I see its reference above?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use jQuery, than you can parse the xml easily this way:

```js
var response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>\
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xpsport2.xsl"?>\
        <Fixtures>\
            <fixtures field="Football">\
                <image1 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.1.0/flags/1x1/be.svg" alt="Belgium"></image1>\
                <image2 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.1.0/flags/1x1/ie.svg" alt="Republic of Ireland"></image2>\
                <match>Belgium v Rep. of Ireland</match>\
                <location>Stade Bollaert-Delelis, Lens</location>\
                <date>Saturday, June 11</date>\
            </fixtures>\
            <fixtures field="Football">\
                <image1 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.1.0/flags/1x1/ie.svg"></image1>\
                <image2 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.1.0/flags/1x1/se.svg"></image2>\
                <match>Rep. of Ireland v Sweden</match>\
                <location>Stade de France, Paris</location>\
                <date> Monday.13 june 2016</date>\
            </fixtures>\
            <fixtures field="Football">\
                <image1 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.1.0/flags/1x1/be.svg" />\
                <image2 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.1.0/flags/1x1/se.svg" />\
                <match> Sweden v Belgium</match>\
                <location>Stade Pierre Mauroy, Lille</location>\
                <date>Tuesday, June 14 </date>\
            </fixtures>\
        </Fixtures>\
';
/* After you get the above text */
var xml = $(response);
xml.find('fixtures').each(function(i){
 var thisFixture = $(this);
 var image1 = thisFixture.find('image1');
 var image2 = thisFixture.find('image2');
 var match = thisFixture.find('match').text();
 var location = thisFixture.find('location').text();
 var date = thisFixture.find('date').text();
 $('div').append(
  '<img src="' + image1.attr('src') + '" />', 
  '<img src="' + image2.attr('src') + '" />', 
  match, 
  location, 
  date, 
  '<br />'
 );
});
```

```css
img {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>We get:</h3>
<div></div>
```

Please note, in order to find root elements as `<Fixture>` is, you would have to wrap the response in a container element, for example:

```
var xml = $('<div>'+response+'</div>');
```

In that case, since

> jQuery parses strings as HTML DOM nodes, which is case-insensitive and
>   normalized to lowercase.

```
console.log( xml.find('fixtures').length );
/* OUTPUT 4! */
```

Comment: Ideally the flag images should print on each side of the text, each flag beside its country.Any suggestions?

Comment: Ideally the flags should display on either side of the text, each flag beside its country. Any ideas ?

Comment: You have all the data you need, the order of content is up to you.